# How to invoke native Module on Main Thread

Tags: reactjs, react-native

click [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7771)

i create a native modeul named RNBroardcast

```
    #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

    @interface RNBroardcast : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

    @end

    RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startBroardcast:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){}
```

this is js code:

```
   var RNBroardcast = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNBroardcast;
   RNBroardcast.startBroardcast((error,events)=>{
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(events);
        }
      });
```

now is the problem:
it worked on 'com.facebook.react.RNBroardcastQueue',how can let it work on main thread.

because my native method must be work on main thread.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204642/how-to-add-a-react-native-native-module-in-application-main-thread