# how to add a react-native native module in application main thread

Tags: react-native

I'm writting a react-native native module using a third-party sdk, it report an error "xxxx should be used only from then application's main thread" when i init the sdk.
How to create a native module in the application's main thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that if you have any code that needs to be run on the main thread, you can use GCD in Objective-C to ensure that.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Code that needs to be run on the main thread.
});
```

By default, React Native runs all of it's code on a separate queue.  In order to specify what queue your module runs on, React Native supplies the `methodQueue` function.  For example, you could specify that *all* of your code in your module runs on the main thread:

```
- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}
```

This would be helpful if your module is creating a native UI component, for example, and has to extensively call into UIKit methods.

Comment: Right,i don't know about mehodQueue  befor , i have serched some usage in the source code about how to use it in ios according to your answer , but few about how to use it in android. Do you know how to implement it in android , Is there any articals or example code i can reference. Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution to implement it in android.
Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runable(){
    // Code that needs to be run on the main thread.
})

Comment: @user1557047 i was required of this method do you guys have nay documentation or something